# Add a number of weeks using a variable as the week amount php

Tags: php

I am trying to use the code seen below to add a specific number of weeks to a starting date. The variable "weekdate" refers to the number of weeks to be added, this can range from 1 all the way up to ∞.
I have taken 1 from each of the dates for a reason that is right but hard to explain but this is not the issue.

What is the mistake I have made here?

```
$weekdate = $row['Week'];
//sets weekdate = 1 -> any number
$weekdate = $weekdate - 1;
//take 1 from that start number
$newdate = date($startdate, strtotime("+" . $weekdate . " Week"));
//add weekdate number of weeks to the start date.
echo $newdate . "<br>";
//echo out.
```

example,

24-10-2016 start date,
+1 week
result output: 31-10-2016

Comment: Works for me. https://3v4l.org/DR2HH

Comment: doesn't have an effect for me

Comment: What does it echo out? Is there an error message?

Comment: Also why do you take away 1 from `$weekdate`? If they want 1 week forward, it will then go to `0`. They need to add an extra week?

Comment: no error, just the same date over and over, despite the week number being added increasing from 0 - 17, there should be 18 dates shown with each one a week in the future

Comment: I need the start week to be from 0 weeks from a date, makes more sense in the context of the use of this data

Comment: So you want something like this? https://3v4l.org/lKYVh

Comment: yes that looks about right

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code. define start date as your variable. i don't have so i put it manually.

```
<?php
$weekdate = 2;
//sets weekdate = 1 -> any number
$weekdate = $weekdate - 1;


$start_date = "2016-10-24";  
$date = strtotime($start_date);
$date = strtotime('+'.$weekdate.' weeks', $date);
echo date('d-m-Y', $date);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the comments, you want something that shows all of the options from the starting point the user puts in.

```
for ($weekdate = $row['Week']; $weekdate >= 0; $weekdate--) {
    $newdate = date('d m y', strtotime("+" . $weekdate . " Week"));
    echo $newdate."\n";
}
```

It will look something like this: https://3v4l.org/lKYVh

If you want the list to be the other way, change the `for` line to be this:

```
for ($weekdate = 0; $weekdate <= 18; $weekdate++) {
```

It will look like this: https://3v4l.org/GmXkB

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Carbon, a very good php library for manipulating dates.

**Installation with composer:**

```
composer require nesbot/carbon
```

then

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

**Installation without composer**

download Carbon.php from https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/Carbon.php

then

```
require 'path/to/Carbon.php';
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

**Usage**

```
$date = Carbon::create(2016,10,24);
$a_week_from_now = $date->addWeek();
//or
$a_week_from_now = $date->addWeeks(1);
$three_weeks_from_now = $date->addWeeks(3);
```

Then you can format the final date however you want it using any of the formats of PHP's DateTime (http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php):

```
$a_week_from_now->format('d-m-Y');  // 31-10-2016
```

Further documentation http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/